# VBA Access Syntax Error in Insert Into Statement

Tags: vba, ms-access

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO tbl_Processor_Info ([Division],[Service_Area],[Service_Line],[Service_Line_Process],[SLA_Type],[SLA_Ref],[Processing_Date],[Total_Processed],[Onshore_Error],[Invalid_Queries],[TAT_Missed],[RFT_Error],[Techinician]) VALUES('" & _
                    .Range("M" & i) & "','" & .Range("I" & i) & "','" & .Range("J" & i) & "','" & .Range("K" & i) & "','" & .Range("N" & i) & "','" & .Range("B" & i) & "',#" & .Range("A" & i) & "#," & .Range("C" & i) & "," & .Range("E" & i) & "," & .Range("F" & i) & "," & .Range("G" & i) & "," & .Range("H" & i) & ",'" & Environ("Username") & "')"
```

results in:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_Processor_Info ([Division],[Service_Area],[Service_Line],[Service_Line_Process],[SLA_Type],[SLA_Ref],[Processing_Date],[Total_Processed],[Onshore_Error],[Invalid_Queries],[TAT_Missed],[RFT_Error],[Techinician]) VALUES('ATA','PUT','DE','PBR','','SP-154',#02/01/2020#,4,,,1,,'arathod')
```

Comment: Please include what `MsgBox strSQL` gives you in your question.

Comment: Msg Is  ----- Run-time error '-2147217900 (80040e14)': Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement

Comment: this connection is with access database

Comment: Some values in VALUES section are skipped at all `(... 4,,,1,,'arathod')` - this is wrong. You must replace such values with some pre-defined (zero, empty string, NULL)...

Comment: Keep in mind that in order for your fields to accept empty strings or null values, your fields have to be set up that way.